# Where are these decimals in my for loop coming from?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, decimal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I'm having some problems with my loop acting funny, here it is:

```
var duration = 1000;  /* 1000 millisecond fade = 1 sec */
var steps = 20;       /* number of opacity intervals   */
var delay = 5000;     /* 5 sec delay before fading out */

function fadeOut(eid) {
  for (i = 0; i <= 1; i += (1 / steps)) {
    setTimeout("setOpacity(" + (1 - i) + ",'"+eid+"')", i * duration);
    console.log("i="+i);
  }

}
```

and I used console.log to check out what's happening on the loop, and it turns out very weird:

```
i=0
i=0.05
i=0.1
i=0.15000000000000002
i=0.2
i=0.25
i=0.3
i=0.35
i=0.39999999999999997
i=0.44999999999999996
i=0.49999999999999994
i=0.5499999999999999
i=0.6
i=0.65
i=0.7000000000000001
i=0.7500000000000001
i=0.8000000000000002
i=0.8500000000000002
i=0.9000000000000002
i=0.9500000000000003
```

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: `i += (1 / steps)` is not a whole number.

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: Do you want to know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: So you suggest using

`setTimeout(function() { setOpacity(1 - i, eid); }, i * duration);`

right? that seems to not work

Answer (score 2):

Those are the actual floating point values. You might want to round them for display purposes.

```
console.log("i="+i.toFixed(2));
```

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html

Comment: But I think it's still affecting my script, it ends at .95 for some reason

Comment: Is is just the log that's wrong, or is that what the values are in the script as well?

Comment: Values are *not* wrong. Those *are* the values of *floating* point numbers. You should read this wiki entry: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point